# How to format response from DynamoDB Scan() API (Python)

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on a API Gateway exercise and I'm stuck formatting the response from DynamoDB. Here is the response I'm getting:

> {'Items': [{'Date': Decimal('3022020'), 'ResultID': Decimal('32'), 'Team': 'Roma', 'League': 'SerieA', 'Result': '3-1'}, {'Date': Decimal('3022020'), 'ResultID': Decimal('31'), 'Team': 'Roma', 'League': 'SerieA', 'Result': '3-1'}, {'Date': Decimal('3022020'), 'ResultID': Decimal('29'), 'Team': 'Roma', 'League': 'SerieA', 'Result': '3-1'}, {'Date': Decimal('3022020'), 'ResultID': Decimal('30'), 'Team': 'Roma', 'League': 'SerieA', 'Result': '3-1'}], 'Count': 4, 'ScannedCount': 11, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'MP2RQ0V4QT898T10DVMMJVMMVRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Sun, 06 Dec 2020 18:29:46 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.0', 'content-length': '487', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': 'MP2RQ0V4QT898T10DVMMJVMMVRVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG', 'x-amz-crc32': '972061714'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

To me it looks like a nested array, but any time I try to play with the response object, it throws me internal server errors. Essentially, the lambda is scanning the database for two attributes (league and team) and returns the results as a response back to the browser as a forced string. Below is kind of the gist of what I have working with that unformatted string object.

```
dbresponse = table.scan(FilterExpression=....)

responseObject = {
    'statusCode': 200
    'body': str(dbresponse)
}

return responseObject
```

I'd like to have something in the `'body':str(dbresponse)` format the response from DynamoDB, but I'm not really sure how to go about it.

Thanks!

*edit*

So it seems like I'm still not really grasping the concept of the 'helper method' as well as I thought I did (see answer below).

I added my non-working version of the helper method inside of the lambda_handler default method. I'm getting some NameErrors, and I assume I'm passing in the object wrong, or calling the attributes in the array or something wrong.

```
def json_response(respDB):
        for response in respDB['Items']:
            response = response + { Date: respDB.Date, 
            League: respDB.League, Team: respDB.Team, 
            Score: respDB.Score }
            
        return response
```

Also, as suggested I'm using this method and passing in the database response variable as the `'body': json_response(respDB)` as suggested.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the response body in JSON yourself.  Try creating a helper method that takes in the output from DynamoDB and outputs formatted JSON.

The helper method should look something like this:

```
def json_response(respDB):
  response = []
  for item in respDB['Items']:
    response.append( { 'Date': item['Date'], 'League': item['League'], 'Team': item['Team']})
            
  return response
```

and use it to build a properly formatted response body

```
dbresponse = table.scan(FilterExpression=....)
responseObject = {
    'statusCode': 200
    'body': format_response(dbresponse)
}

return responseObject
```

Comment: Thanks! I was attempting to do that but with python (badly). I'll give it a shot and let you know!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your help. I'm still not really grasping it, so I edited my original question up top, as it's a little easier to read.

Comment: I updated my answer with a working python example. I'm not a python developer, but I hope this gets you unstuck.  You might want to check out the boto3 code examples: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/dynamodb.html. The AWS docs might help as well: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.Python.html

Comment: Looks like that did the trick! Just so I'm tracking the logic... The helper method is passed the scan() object, response is declared as a list, the loop (which was what I was badly trying to accomplish) the picks out each attribute we want and throws it into the response list. Sound right?

Comment: I believe the response object is a dictionary, but the response['Items'] value will be a list.  Either way, you've got the right idea.